# What's a nice way of building a wParam or lParam in C#? (Something friendlier than shift operators?)

Tags: c#, winapi

When the WIN32 docs says something like:

```
wParam
    The low-order word specifies the edit control identifier.
    The high-order word specifies the notification message.
```

What's a nice way of building that wParam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static ushort LowWord(uint val)
{
    return (ushort)val;
}

public static ushort HighWord(uint val)
{
   return (ushort)(val >> 16);
}

public static uint BuildWParam(ushort low, ushort high)
{
    return ((uint)high << 16) | (uint)low;
}
```

Comment: Ah - thanks.   uint BuildWParam(ushort low, ushort high) { return ((uint)low << 16) | (uint)high; }