# Detecting XBUTTON1 in PreFilterMessage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I'm trying to detect a mouse's **XBUTTON1** and **XBUTTON2** clicks using [PreFilterMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.prefiltermessage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as suggested in an answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312587/capture-mouse-click-anywhere-on-form-without-imessagefilter), but am unsure about the how to read the **WPARAM**.

According to the [WM_XBUTTONDOWN msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)   , I have to check the **WPARAM**'s "high-order word" in order to distinguish between the two buttons. However, it seems from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515261/what-are-the-definitions-for-lparam-and-wparam)  that the size of **WPARAM** is different in x86 and x64. So how do I make sure it works on both?

Comment: Read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202330/whats-a-nice-way-of-building-a-wparam-or-lparam-in-c-something-friendlier-th

Comment: @DonBoitnott Thanks. But that assumes that it's really a `uint`. Can it change sometimes (x86 vs x64)?

Comment: I'm not certain, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153548(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests perhaps it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hey ispiro did you find solution to this?

Comment: @Noitidart I'm not certain, but I think I went with trusting the msdn link [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315352/detecting-xbutton1-in-prefiltermessage?noredirect=1#comment32127942_21315352).

Comment: Thanks @ispiro man, may you share your code if possible?

Comment: @Noitidart Sorry. I doubt we ended up implementing it, and even if so, I don’t have it available. But you can ask a question about it. (Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/202383/939213 can help you?)

Comment: Darn no problem, thanks man!